# Changing CSS parameters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.makebig {
    -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(150px);
    }
}
.makesmall {
    -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation1 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(150px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }
}
```

And this Javascript:

```
<script>
    function ani(fns1) {
    if (document.getElementById('fns1').getAttribute('clicked') == 'false') 
    {
        document.getElementById('fns1').className = 'makebig';
        document.getElementById('fns1').setAttribute('clicked', true);
    } else { 
        document.getElementById('fns1').className = 'makesmall';
        document.getElementById('fns1').setAttribute('clicked', false);
    }
}
</script>
```

The code scales the object in two times. How can I send different 'scale' parameters based on the object?

I use it for the images to enlarge onclick and go to original scale on the second click.
My images has different size and position in the text, so i need to make them scaled in center of the screen.

Comment: i'm using just JS and CSS, but for the IOS app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use transition instead of an animation

```
.makebig {
    transition: 1s transform ease;
}
```

then you can set the desired end transform on each element individually with js and the browser will animate it accordingly

Comment: Not sure that it will suit. I've modified my first question with full text. Do you think it will work in my case? 
I make it for IOS browser.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's changed. Here's a fiddle demonstrating http://jsfiddle.net/qkrby/1/. You could pretty easily extrapolate from there to parameterize the target and size. Does that make things clearer?

Answer (score 1):

you could hardcode several css classes and animations to suit your needs:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scale-1 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(150px);
    }
}


@-webkit-keyframes scale-2 {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3) skew(0deg) translate(150px);
    }
}

#element {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#element.scale-1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: scale-1;
}

#element.scale-2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: scale-1;
}
```

and just juggle with classnames from js:

```
element.className = 'scale-1';
// after some logic
element.className = 'scale-2';
```

Comment: gion_13, can't do this, as i will need also calculate size of object, it's position (float left or right) and maybe other parameters to modify.